# Unable to upload files into Godaddy server

Tags: c#, asp.net, shared-hosting

When i try to upload the Image to the Godaddy , i'm only able to upload lesser size of images .

I have already used this in my web-config , but still i am unable to upload the larger files

```
 <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting..

Comment: @Webruster something like `MaxRequest` length reached error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you web config you need to add `maxRequestLength` in `System.web` along with the above config

Ex:

```
 <httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="600000" />
```

Comment: i am able to upload in the localhost but can't able to do in  real site.. can you help me with it please?

Comment: sure will add and ask you

Comment: please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43693699/how-to-add-the-audio-tag-in-the-ckeditor