# How to add the audio tag in the CKeditor

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor

I have added the `html5audio` plugin and able to get the Upload button , but how to send the uploaded file to the server.

Here is my plugin Code

```
{
        id: 'Upload',
        hidden: false,
        filebrowser: 'uploadButton',
        label: editor.lang.html5audio.upload,
        elements: [ {
            type: 'file',
            id: 'upload',
            label: editor.lang.html5audio.btnUpload,
            style: 'height:40px',
            size: 38
        },
        {
            type: 'fileButton',
            id: 'uploadButton',
            filebrowser: 'info:url',
            label: editor.lang.html5audio.btnUpload,
            'for': [ 'Upload', 'upload' ]
        } ]
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create `handler` to send ther uploaded files to the server

**Handler**

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Upload" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class Upload : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

        HttpPostedFile uploads = context.Request.Files["upload"];
        string CKEditorFuncNum = context.Request["CKEditorFuncNum"];
         string file = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploads.FileName);
        uploads.SaveAs(context.Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Audio\\" + file);

      //  string url =  "/ckeditor/Images/" + file;
        string url =  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CKEditorAudioUrl"].ToString() + file;
        context.Response.Write("<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(" + CKEditorFuncNum + ", \"" + url + "\");</script>");
        context.Response.End();  

    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

In your Config file you need to update

```
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = 'Path to your Handler;
```

Comment: @runner try to check  in developer tool , that config file is updated or not